# How to open a link in new window with tab enabled

Tags: javascript

I search a lot but could not figured it out.

Is it possible to open a new window with tab enabled using `window.open()` method?.
The way chrome context menu "open link in new window" works.

Comment: What does that mean `tab enabled`?

Comment: @Neal when for me window.open used to open a new window where I cannot create a new tab. Is it possible to create a tab in children window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The browser decides on its own how links will open. Sometimes a user can configure how links are to be opened, but the web page cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

using an [anchor tag](http://www.aitechsolutions.net/htmlhowAtargetattrib.html) you can set the `target` attribute to have *some* control over where the link opens. Other than that, this behavior is up to the browser and user and cannot be controlled by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
window.open("http:.//www.google.com","DemoName",'scrollbars=1,height=650,width=1050');
```